# Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups, sync

I have used following script to add a domain group to a site

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser]$spuser = $web.EnsureUser("WM\My Group name")  
Set-SPUser -Identity $spuser -Web "http://myweb" -AddPermissionLevel "Läsa"
```

Now I run following script to update (sync) the group from AD

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://myweb" //is root web
$user = $web | Get-SPUser -Identity "WM\My Group name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$web | Set-SPUser -Identity $user -SyncFromAD
```

but it says Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user "WM\My Group name"

any idea why? thanks

Comment: Do the user names show in central admin in the user profile manager service? Does the user you are running the script as have the permissions to the service?

Comment: No, I can't find the profile in UPS find profiles.